# Overlay mesh is transparent for certain material colors in Forge 3D viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I'm trying to add custom geometry to my forge viewer, following [this  example](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/). It mostly works fine, except when using certain colors.

I'm using the following code to add a sphere mesh:

```js
        const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.4, 32, 32)
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: someColor,
            transparent: false,
        })
        const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

        viewer.overlays.addScene('sphere-mesh-scene')
        viewer.overlays.addMesh(sphere, 'sphere-mesh-scene')
```

for certain values of `someColor` the sphere is transparent, for other values, it's not:
e.g.

`#6b6e75` and `#54ffff` yields a transparent sphere,
while
`#000000` and `#988888` yields an opaque sphere.

Is there any material properties I need to set to avoid this? Or do I need to deal with the material manager in forge?

I'm using forge viewer version 7.14.0.

**Edit**

I also get the same result for point clouds - with a point cloud with many different colors, some of the points are transparent, and get a "glowing outline" against the Forge geometry.

Comment: Can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue and will have a word with Engineering for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happending because by default the blend shader determines if it should add transparency (to selected nodes for instance) by its hue color in the overlay...

We can suppress this behavior by turning `useIdBufferSelection` in the `initOptions` like below when calling `viewer.start/loadModel(svf,options,cb,cb,cb,initOptions)`:

```
viewer.loadModel(svf,null,null,null,{useIdBufferSelection:true});
```

See live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/capozu/edit?js)