# How to colorizing larg number of items using dbIds in fastest way?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to colorize a huge model based on special categories, where each category refers to about 1000 dbIds. I know if I color the parent node, all child node get colored very fast. However the dbIds in each categories that I have, mostly don't have same parent and I have to run viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, color); for each dbId separately, which take very long time to process.
Is there any faster way to colorizing the model in this case?

I illustrated my customized tree to categorizing model and its relation with the default Forge model browser tree in the image bellow.

[Left side is default Forge Model browser - Right side is my customized model navigation tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlMXH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively set the color of all children under a node by flipping the recursive flag with:

```
NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor(dbid, THREE.Vector4, null, true)
```

And when applying colors to large numbers of objects we might end up with a perceivable performance hit so here is how to defer the rendering of these colors until all the codes to the objects and then render them altogether instead of re-render every time for each individual object:

```
model.setThemingColor(dbid1, THREE.Vector4); //calling setThemingColor on the model object only marks the object for coloring w/o triggering rendering immediately
model.setThemingColor(dbid2, THREE.Vector4);
//...
NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true)   //trigger rendering afterwards
```

See more [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/revisiting-viewers-theming-coloring-selective-cancelling-deferred-rendering-and-recursive)

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I used "NOP_VIEWER.setThemingColor(dbid, THREE.Vector4, null, true)" and now the coloring is so fast. But now there is an other problem came up.  After coloring, when the colored items (specially large number of colored items) are selected, Those are shown transparent, highlighted and get performance hit, then rendering would be so slow. But when I deselect, then the rendering is so smooth and fast. Do you you what the reason is?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60717863/overlay-mesh-is-transparent-for-certain-material-colors-in-forge-3d-viewer?r=SearchResults&s=1|142.0046) - try the option described in the answer and see if that fixes it and if not start a new question so we can look into it ...

Answer (score -1):

What I did is hiding the whole model. Then coloring when the model is hidden.

```
$('.spinner').show();
this.viewerComponent.viewer.setGhosting(false);
this.viewerComponent.viewer.hide(this.viewerComponent.viewer.model.getRootId());
this.viewerComponent.viewer.search(name, (idArray) => {
 this.viewerComponent.viewer.setThemingColor(idArray[0], color, 
 this.viewerComponent.viewer.model, true);
   iterator += 1;
   // Wenn iterator gleich die Länge ist dass alle Objekte wieder zeigen
   // Korrektion für coloredElements.length !== this.inputs.length
   if (iterator === this.inputs.length - 50) {
     $('.spinner').hide();
     this.viewerComponent.viewer.showAll();
     }
   }, (err) => {
     this.messageService.add({ key: 'warning', severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', 
     detail: 'Something with COLORING went wrong: ' + err });
   }, ['name']);
```

Best,