# Autodesk Forge: Transparent objects in overlay scenes turn opaque

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a Forge scene with some semi-transparent custom geometry. After upgrading to version 7.21.0 of the Forge viewer, we had to move the custom geometry to an overlay scene, as described in the [Forge guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/). The resulting geometry is semi-transparent while navigating, but turns opaque about half a second after stopping.

This code can be used for testing on http://lmv.ninja.autodesk.com. In this example, you can see the blue sphere through the green one, but once you hover over the plane (I tested the Toy Plane model), you cannot.

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20,32,32)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: '#00ff00',
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
    })
const sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
sphere1.position.y = 90
NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addScene('custom-scene')
NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addMesh(sphere1, 'custom-scene')

const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '#0000ff'})
const sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.clone(), material2)
sphere2.position.y = 60

NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addMesh(sphere2, 'custom-scene')
```

How do I make the geometry stay transparent?

I have tried setting `useIdBufferSelection: true`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60831744/623343).

Setting `depthTest: false` or `depthWrite: false` in the material fixes the transparency issue, but (unsurprisingly) breaks the order of rendering, so that close objects may appear behind far away objects.

Comment: I tried your code in the Developer Console on http://lmv.ninja.autodesk.com/ with the "Toy Plane" model. The sphere will end up right in the middle of the top cover of the seat and for me it stayed transparent. Does it work for you there too?

Comment: @AdamNagy Thanks for your response. I'm afraid I haven't used lmv.ninja.autodesk.com before - how do I get hold of the scene?

Comment: Use can use NOP_VIEWER https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/do-simple-viewer-api-tests-quickly

Comment: Ok, that works for me too. I guess I'll have to investigate a bit more to make a reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamNagy The transparency problem seems to only relate to other geometry in an overlay scene. I updated the code to something that shows it on lmv.ninja.autodesk.com.

Answer (score 0):

**Backgrounder:**
The problem is THREE.js doesn't handle overlapping transparency very well.
ForgeViewer has a special multi-pass renderer, that renders diffuse objects first, then blends overlapping transparent objects.  It's not as accurate as OIT, but it's good enough.

Unfortunately, the viewer.impl.**scene** and impl.**sceneAfter** and **overlay**, all use the standard THREE.js traverser, which doesn't handle overlapping transparent objects... BUT ! ....

You can try these workarounds:

1. Draw your meshes with LMV.SceneBuilder (which elevates three.js mesh objects into LMV geometrybuffer objects) (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer)
2. Force 'double sided' renderering to your three.js transparent materials.  Still not perfect, but worth a shot

Comment: Thank you. I tested the SceneBuilder example at https://codepen.io/petrbroz/pen/gOaaoxz.
I changed the material of the red box with `transparent: true` and `opacity: 0.5`, and it partially works. I can see the other custom geometry through it, but not the house. Any idea how to make that work?
I also tried to enable double sided rendering, that didn't change anything for me.